# src absolute path not showing video

Tags: php, html, css

I have a function that searches for a folder and then selects a random video.

```
function random_video($dirName = "//sv-sstnl-nas\Public\Website Entree\Movies/")
    {
        $files = array_merge(glob($dirName . "*.m4v"), glob($dirName . "*.mp4"), glob($dirName . "*.mov"));
        $file = array_rand($files);
        return $files[$file];
    }

    $raw_vid_name = random_video();
    $vid_name = substr($raw_vid_name, 44, -4);  // Remove first 44 Characters, Remove last 4 Characters
```

Then i want to show a random video.

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay controls>
    <source src="<?php echo $raw_vid_name; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Now this worked when i had my directory in /videos/

However right now, i want it in a shared drive.

The code above works. At the top of the video, i see the name of the current video. However it does not play anything.

When i go to inspect element, it says:

[image: Inspect Element]

And on the website i see:

[image: Website]

As you can see, the src is right (in my opinion).

However the video player plays nothing.

How do i solve this, and why does this happen?

***EDIT:***

I changed

```
    <source src="<?php echo $raw_vid_name; ?>" type="video/mp4">
```

to

```
    <source src="file://<?php echo $raw_vid_name; ?>" type="video/mp4">
```

Now when i inspect the element, it shows me:

**file:////sv-sstnl-nas\Public\Website Entree\Movies/main.mp4**

When i enter this link to my browser, it plays the video.

But it still does not play the video :/

Comment: just a hint, that array_merge of globs is a performance killer, please use `$files = glob($dirName."*.{mp4,mov,m4v}",GLOB_BRACE)` instead - maybe add http(s): in front of that sourceurl? is this the right path?

Comment: Check your slashes . based on ur OS use "\" or "/"

Comment: Changed it to: $files = glob($dirName."*.{mp4,mov,m4v}",GLOB_BRACE); & Changed it to $dirName = "//sv-sstnl-nas/Public/Website Entree/Movies/" Still same result. it finds the folder and title. but somehow does not want to display it

Comment: @UnskilledFreak & Mangesh, i made a EDIT.

Comment: whitespaces in urls --> `str_replace(" ","%20",$raw_vid_name)` ur just simply use `urlencode()`

Comment: Still does the same @UnskilledFreak

Comment: did u checked the network and console panel in debugger? looks like chrome so if the file is not found or other errors will be stored there - if there are non then there's something other wrong with it